# Firefox 5 doesn t render style font-weight: 900

Tags: css, firefox

Is this a known bug?

my test text is not rendered bold within a firefox 5 only in firefox 4.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6Trxg/2/

**Edit**: If you're expecting `900` to be bolder than `bold` then that's not guaranteed to work - [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness) says:

*"There is no guarantee that there will be a darker face for each of the 'font-weight' values; for example, some fonts may have only a normal and a bold face [...] There is no guarantee on how a UA will map font faces within a family to weight values. The only guarantee is that a face of a given value will be no less dark than the faces of lighter values."*

Comment: you dont use font-weight 900 in your example?!

Comment: Sorry - finger trouble, now fixed.  :-)

Comment: i still cannot see a rule font-weight 900 :-(

Comment: ah now i see the  rule but font weight 900 is the same as bold but should be bolder. Is this a bug?

Comment: @cssShame Yes and no. Browsers actually support just normal and bold text, not multiple levels of font-weight. `font-weight:900` will look the same as `font-weight:700`.

Comment: And finally my last question, how do i achieve a font weight 900 if the value is not supported any more?

Comment: Support for `900` hasn't changed - it will always give you a font that is at least as bold as `bold`.  If your problem is that a previous version of a browser gave you bolder-than-bold and it no longer does, that's still within spec.  You could submit a bug report for that browser asking for the previous behaviour to be restored, but it could legitimately be declined.